# redirect to /wp-admin/edit.php instead of wp_redirect url

Tags: wp-redirect

I´m trying for a custom post type to make changes on the admin edit post page by a link with params.
The problem is when I´m trying to redirect to the page without these custom params thanks `wp_redirect()`.

This is my code in a class:

```
    add_action('admin_init',array( $this, 'foo_actions' ) );

    function  foo_actions(){
         if( isset( $_GET['foo_action'] ) ){
                // ob_clean();
                // ob_start();
                $order_id = (int) $_GET['post'];
                switch ( $_GET['foo_action'] ) {
                    case ACTION_RENEW_PLAN :
                        Orders::renew_plan($order_id);
                        break;
                    case ACTION_UNRENEW_PLAN :
                        Orders::unrenew_plan($order_id);
                        break;
                    case ACTION_ENABLE_AUTO_PLAN_RENEWED :
                        Orders::enable_auto_plan_renewed($order_id);
                        break;
                    case ACTION_DISABLE_AUTO_PLAN_RENEWED :
                        Orders::disable_auto_plan_renewed($order_id);
                        break;
                } 
                $edit_post_link = get_edit_post_link($order_id);
                wp_redirect( $edit_post_link );
                exit();
         }
    }
```

This code redirect to `/wp-admin/edit.php` instead of `$edit_post_link`.
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the second parameter for [`get_edit_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/), which is `$context` and defaults to `display`. And that parameter determines how to output the ampersand character (i.e. `&`), which defaults to being encoded as `&amp;` (because the default context is that the URL is being displayed, hence the `&` is encoded).

- When using the URL with redirection, you would want to use the `edit` (or anything other than `display`) context:

  ```php
  $edit_post_link = get_edit_post_link( $order_id, 'edit' );
  wp_redirect( $edit_post_link );
  ```
- When displaying the URL, you would use the `display` context:

  ```php
  $edit_post_link = get_edit_post_link( $order_id, 'display' );

  // Or you can simply ignore the second parameter:
  $edit_post_link = get_edit_post_link( $order_id );

  var_dump( $edit_post_link ); // & becomes &amp;
  ```